# Export Postgresql table data using pgAdmin

Tags: database, postgresql, export, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin version 1.14.3. PostgreSQL database version is 9.1.

I got all Db script for table creation but unable to export all data inside tables. Could not find any option to export data in db script form.

Comment: If anyone want for whole DB then look [Export and Import of PostgresSQL with pgAdmin III](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39167526/1045444)

Comment: You can try in online demo http://choose.tools/tool?id=pgAdmin

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Just right click on a table and select "backup". The popup will show various options, including "Format", select "plain" and you get plain SQL.

pgAdmin is just using [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) to create the dump, also when you want plain SQL.

It uses something like this:

> pg_dump --user user --password --format=plain --table=tablename --inserts --attribute-inserts etc.

Comment: it generates dump having table data script starts with COPY command not INSERT. Anyway to generate script with INSERT commands.

Comment: That's why you have to create plain SQL. When using the dump option INSERT, you get ordinary INSERT queries

Comment: Can you tell where to use this dump option INSERT

Comment: "Dump Option #1" => "Use INSERT ..."

Comment: On the command line, pg_dump is a command line tool. Or use pg_dump and click on the correct tabs to select the options you need.

Comment: This creates an INSERT command for each row, as opposed to one INSERT with all the row values (which has better performance). I couldn't find an option to change it but a simple find and replace worked for me.

Comment: @Pixel Elephant: If performance matters, you should use COPY. It's much faster.

Comment: In pgAdmin III 1.16.1, "Use Insert commands" is under Dump Option #2.

Comment: In pgAdmin III 1.18.1, Select Plain for Format under File Option and than check "Use Insert commands" under Dump Option #2.

Comment: Maybe this work if your DB is in local. In my case, there is a message announcing the victory, but the file disappears on the server. I want to DOWNLOAD it on my computer. :/

Answer (score 226):

1. Right-click on your table and pick option `Backup`..
2. On File Options, set Filepath/Filename and pick `PLAIN` for Format
3. Ignore Dump Options #1 tab
4. In Dump Options #2 tab, check `USE INSERT COMMANDS`
5. In Dump Options #2 tab, check `Use Column Inserts` if you want column names in your inserts.
6. Hit `Backup` button

Edit: **In case you are using pgAdmin on a remote server: Once the UI announces the backup was successful, you might want to download the data. For this, follow these steps**:

1. Click on Tools (in the menu)
2. Select Storage Manager
3. Select the file that was just created
4. Click on the small "Download File" button

Comment: where this backup went?

Comment: Maybe this work if your DB is in local. In my case, there is a message announcing the victory, but the file disappears on the server. I want to DOWNLOAD it on my computer. :/

Comment: pgAdmin is most ridiculous IT tools I've ever used. There's anything like UX in pgAdmin.

Comment: I couldn't find the file that was generated, so I ended up using the command that pgAdmin used (click on "More Details" in pgAdmin after running Backup), and opening a shell on the server and running the same command, then I could copy the file.

Comment: for File Name give a file with a full path (eg: /home/xxx/yyy/backup.sql"), Then if it gives an error saying cannot find that message has the default path it tries to save.

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas backup file is created under Documents folder in Windows OS.

Comment: @fresko see my edit on how to download the backup from a server

Comment: try to create an empty text file and change the extension of it to .sql. Select the file

Answer (score 24):

In the pgAdmin4, Right click on table select backup like this

[image]

After that into the backup dialog there is **Dump options** tab into that there is section queries you can select **Use Insert Commands** which include all insert queries as well in the backup.

[image]