# How to backup postgres db hosted on cloud with pgadmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm hosting my db using AWS RDS and I'm trying to backup tables. However once it's finished backing up, where is the downloaded on my computer?

[image]

Doesn't seem like theres a path to save the file

[image]

I've checked a couple of answers and others are having same issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29246636/11110509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Filename" element in that dialog box lets you pick a directory as well as file name.  That is where it is.  If you just typed in a filename without giving a path, then on Windows it is probably in your user's "Documents" folder.