# How to export Postgres schema/data to plain SQL in PgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I read a few similar posts and find that they did not specify how to export SQLs to custom files. I will walk through steps with screenshots here.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257132/export-postgresql-table-data-using-pgadmin)
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784598/export-db-with-postgresqls-pgadmin-iii/39167526#39167526)

Answer (score 15):

1. right click on a table/schema/database and click 'Backup' in the menu.

> [image]

2. set export file format to 'Plain'

> [image]

3. select the custom file created to save the backup scripts

> [image]

and double click to confirm

> [image]

4. open 'dump options' tab to set dump options

> [image]

5. set dump options

> [image]
>
> [image]

6. set 'Use INSERT commands' so the exported sql is runnable when original table/schema/database is deleted

> [image]

7. click 'Backup' button to start process

> [image]

8. PgAdmin shows success message when backup is done

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a Store Manager under Tools that allows you to download a backup explained in the answer above. Took me a while to find it. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]